# How to compare string in java using scanner object

Tags: java

I have a question about how to compare string in java using scanner object? . The things that I have to compare is 4 states and capital respectively.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
    String myString1 =  new String ("state");
    String myString2 =  new String ("capitalstate");

    System.out.println ("input state");
    myString1=input.next(); 


    if (myString1.equals("malaysia"))
    {
        myString2 = "kuala lumpur";
        System.out.println ("capital state for " +myString1+ " is " +myString2);
    }



    else if (myString1.equals("south korean"))
    {
        myString2 = "seoul";
        System.out.println ("capital state for " +myString1+ " is " +myString2);
    }
```

Comment: You are comparing the String so what is your question?  Is this a good way? no, use a Map instead, But will it work? sure.

Comment: are you looking for : myString1.equals ( scannerObj.next() )?

Comment: `next()` will read up to the next space, so `mystring1.equals("south korean")` will always return false.

Comment: its for my assignment and i'm still noob about it. @PeterLawrey

Comment: In that case, I suggest trying to make your question clearer.  This forum is not a general code review site.  You need to ask a specific question to get an answer.

Comment: Is your code working ? Your code seems fine and should work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify problem you are facing. As it stays it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: yes its working. thanks to you @PritamBanerjee .

Comment: You should avoid using `new String();` since you're using string literals.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code can be the following and should work fine:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String myString1 =  new String ("state");
String myString2 =  new String ("capitalstate");

System.out.println ("input state");
myString1=input.next(); 

if (myString1.contains("malaysia"))
   {
     myString2 = "kuala lumpur";
     System.out.println ("capital state for " +myString1+ " is " +myString2);
    }

else if (myString1.equals("south korean"))
    {
      myString2 = "seoul";
      System.out.println ("capital state for " +myString1+ " is " +myString2);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think it will solve the problem? Can you explain your solution so OP and other readers could learn what was the problem and why you think this code should work?

Comment: Because in that case if he has some trailing spaces it will always give the right answer

Comment: What trailing spaces? Notice that `myString1` is result of `input.next();`.

Comment: Otherwise I don't see any error in his code. That could be the only problem.